# Is there a way to return a cell value if two arrays associated with that value are equal?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have a data set that details out specific discounts based on a store number, that data set looks similar to this:

[image: Store Discount Data Set]

My two questions are:

Is there a way to pull out the unique arrays within the data set using formulas? (The arrays are a set size of columns and rows within the data set)

Is there a way to get a unique list of stores that fit the criteria of each unique array?

In this example I am trying to get something like this to return:

[image: Return Values]

I've been able to build a workaround by assigning specific areas of the worksheet as Array1, Array2, etc. and then using a formula to check if the individual arrays for each store are equal but I'm looking for a quicker way to easily pull out the unique arrays and associated stores.

Comment: What would you like as the unique definition? Are you just looking for the column 'Associated Stores' based on the Unique Arrays table? Or the whole result of your second image to be the formula?

Comment: I would unpivot your data, and then put it into a pivot table for easier filtering. https://trumpexcel.com/unpivot-data/

Comment: Please put the input data in table markdown format, you can use this [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#), just copy from your excel, then generate it and copy it back to the question. It takes time to reproduce your input data. Thanks